# Why put Edge questions on hold?

Tags: discussion

I have seen many Ubuntu Edge questions being put on hold because they are not ubuntu. It is stated that it should be asked on the fundraiser page, why are you doing this?

First off, commenting on the fundraiser page requires making an account on igg, and also it is not made for questions that need answers. If I would ask a question there it would be buried within 20 minutes in unrelated questions that cant be filtered out, and even if I would get a reply, I would stand no chance in finding this answer.

People cannot spend 800 dollars if they cannot first get confirmation on ESSENTIAL questions. Such as "will it work in my country?", which is a very non-trivial question for anyone outside Europe or the US. This absolutely NEEDS to be answered. If you look at the dip in pledges during the Asian daytime it is quite clear that people in Asia cannot be sure, and at current rate, the campaign will only(uhm, yeah..) reach 25million.

So please, if you want this fundraiser to be successful, let people ask and answer questions on those kinds of things, since it does have it's own tag. If you have another suggestion to where to ask and answer these questions, please answer me that. But I believe these questions should be answered at as many places as possible, and preferably by clear statements from the Ubuntu Edge team. (I have a feeling they wont really go through the 3000+ comments on the fundraiser page.)

Comment: He also stated in the reddit AMA that not all bands would be supported. This is why I think those kinds of questions would be viable on askubuntu, because they are ubuntu-edge related questions that can be answered, not by the information given, but from the information plus general knowledge of LTE infrastructure.

Comment: by the same logic no x server or linux kernel questions should be asked at askubuntu.

Comment: I'm not trying to ask a question, I just think that a certain kind of ubuntu edge related questions should be viable. If not, explain to me the viability of the tag ubuntu-edge? if questions that are not even speculative cannot be asked?

Comment: This question is in no way less speculative than the question for if it will work in japan? Granted that the question should have started with "Given the information available..", but that is simply a problem of question format which should be edited to fit askubuntu. The question you linked is also in larger extent of the category of answered simply by a link, while it apparently needed clarification.

Comment: I'm just going to give up now since you have a valid answer below and refuses to accept that as an answer to your question...

Comment: I will accept that answer then. But I do feel that the actual practices do not comply with the answer. It would be nice if any non-speculative answer would not be put on hold, and questions that can be changed into non-speculative answers be simply edited to comply with this.

Comment: well on the question will it work in Japana, yes it will if you have power to charge the phone. That's really all we know. And that's all the information that's given so why ask it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Mark, or the campaign has released specifics we can flag to reopen the question/s,

If not... there are thousands of comments on the campaign, and Reddit that speculate *which* bands or will he really put an IR on the phone...

I suggest your best avenue is to use the e-mail on the [campaign page](http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/ubuntu-edge/x/1680448), as it

- Does not require a Indigogo account.
- Will be easier to ask specific - I live in <>  country with <> carrier. Because every time they answer elsewhere it is the same information that is already on the FAQ page.

Here is the part of the FAQ:

> What if my question isn’t answered here?
>
> We’re happy to respond to any other queries you might have about the
>   Ubuntu Edge, the Indiegogo campaign, and our company as a whole. Email
>   us at indiegogoinfo@canonical.com

---

Now, Does that mean we are closing *all* edge questions? Certainly not.

If we get a question that is "What are the 'two LTE standards` referred by the Edge project". That could be an answerable question - it is not "Will the phone work in..." which we can not predict or guarantee.

Granted maybe some should be closed as "Unclear what your asking" because how should we know what standards are in use in a certain country, A bit more information is needed.

Answer (score 11):

It's more about the fact, that this edge project is not done yet. There are no Prototypes which shows all technical details yet. So we don't know more about Edge than the official page : [idiegogo Ubuntu Edge](http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/ubuntu-edge) . Most of the questions are about things that will be revealed later, so there is no real answer. Thats not part of this Page. Correct me if i missunderstood something.

Comment: Well, the thing is that some people are much better at interpreting the information given at the igg page, asking here would most likely improve the chance the information given is understood correctly. Many questions can be answered on general knowledge not specific to the Ubuntu Edge.

Comment: @nisse then many questions don't have to asked at all since it will just be a link to the page about Ubuntu edge...

Comment: This is right. We close speculative questions because they cannot be answered, even by Canonical employees. They have no place on a Q&A site. Use Ubuntu Forums if you want to chat about things.

Comment: "Not understanding the information" does not equal to "did not read the information", there is much implied information in the given information that is hard to interpret for many people, for someone that doesn't have the required knowledge to get all the implied information the question cannot be answered by any link to a page about the Ubuntu Edge. Unless it's a page that answers questions. By your logic any question on askubuntu can be asked with a link to a page about Ubuntu.

Comment: @Nisse No my point was that link-to-answer aren't really welcome here since it's not an answer just a hint on where to look for answers.

Comment: While some questions are speculative, the question "Does this mean that the Edge will work in my country" is an example of a non-speculative answer, it is possible to answer in a completely non-speculative way. "Supporting both LTE standards means support in X" or "it is impossible to know until the supported bands are made public" would be non-speculative answers to this question.

Comment: Good answer. Likewise questions about Ubuntu+1 (unreleased development version) are off-topic. If the Edge isn't out yet, most of it is still subject to change.